# HTML style mark-down language so that people can color English words a different color than French words

Tags: feature-request

Il s'agit d'une demande de fonctionnalité pour changer la langue de démarquage afin que les utilisateurs puissent colorer les mots anglais d'une couleur différente des mots français dans leurs questions.

```
Quel mot le professeur ou instructeur de mathématiques français,
qui enseigne aux enfants, utilise-t-il pour les <teal>spectrums<\teal> ?
```

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF PROTOTYPE CONSCEPT ART]

Comment: Pourquoi ?  Le gras ne fais rien ? 
 Puis comment choisir la couleur d'une langue ?  En effet une autre règle à apprendre pour ceux qui apprennent déjà un autre code, la langue ?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the point of such a request. Linguists use "quotation marks" / « guillemets » or *italics*. Adding more HTML tags would only cause pages to upload more slowly. Waste of time and energy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is technically feasible as described (edit: having custom markup for a SO subsite that differs from the standard one), but I concur with the premise of the request.

It is currently not obvious how to best contrast example sentences embedded in answer text, or sentences in different languages, visually.
As far as I know, there is no entry in the Help Center about how to format the different parts of an answer: English sentences, French sentences, book excerpts vs made-up examples, fictional dialogue, etc.

A template answer showcasing all kinds of formatting to make an A more readable could be useful.

Comment: Actually, Math SE [does have custom markdown to allow the use of LaTeX](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex), so it might be technically feasible. (No opinion on whether it's a good idea or not.)